# finding initial guesses for exponential curve fit

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, exponential-distribution

So I don't know how to do this, and I'm not sure if there's some math that I'm completely forgetting right now but I'm at a loss.  In short, I have some fairly simple initial code using scipy and numpy, and I want to fit an exponential curve to it:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

# sample data
x = np.array([7620.,   7730.,   7901.,   8139.,   8370.,   8448.,   8737.,   8824., 9089.,   9233.,   9321.,   9509.,   9568.,   9642.,   9756.,   9915.,  10601., 10942.])
y = np.array([0.01228478,  0.01280466,  0.01363498,  0.01493918,  0.01530108, 0.01569484,  0.01628133,  0.01547824,  0.0171548,   0.01743745,  0.01776848, 0.01773898,  0.01839569,  0.01823377,  0.01843686,  0.01875542,  0.01881426, 0.01977975])

# define type of function to search
def model_func(x, a, k, b):
    return a * np.exp(-k*x) + b

# curve fit
p0 = (2.e-6,300,1)
opt, pcov = curve_fit(model_func, x, y, p0)
a, k, b = opt
# test result
x2 = np.linspace(7228, 11000, 3000)
y2 = model_func(x2, a, k, b)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x2, y2, color='r', label='Fit. func: $f(x) = %.3f e^{%.3f x} %+.3f$' % (a,k,b))
ax.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='data with noise')
ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

My issue is try as I may I can't figure out the initial parameters for p0- I've tried a range of values, but frankly I have no idea what I'm doing so I'm not getting a solution here.  Can someone suggest how to do it?  Thank you!

Comment: FYI: @MNewville has some useful suggestions for fitting an exponential here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312404/new-error-in-old-code-in-numpy-exp/45314363#45314363

Comment: Looking at your data, you should start with a negative value for `a`.  And probably not quite such a big one for `k`, but I guess Levenberg-Marquardt will sort this out for you.

Comment: Be aware that working in log space is not an option for your model because of the additive constant `b`.

Comment: I haven't used curve_fit before, but this point seems to produce an expected result: p0 = (-2, 1.0/7000, 1)

Comment: The authors of scipy added the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm as the module scipy.optimize.differential_evolution for the purpose of estimating initial parameters for their non-linear solvers. An example of fitting a double Lorentzian peak equation to carbon nanotube Raman spectroscopy data using this scipy module for initial parameter estimation is here: https://github.com/zunzun/RamanSpectroscopyFit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this data is more close to a lign than an exponential curve, are you sure your model is right?

About the initial guesses, I assume you don't have any further knowledge about the function, if so use it:

For x->\inf the fucntion approaches b. So I would use a guess of about 0.025 for b.
For the other two variables, take a subsample of `x` and `y` and solve the equation explicit:

```
a * np.exp(-k*x[0]) + 0.025 = y[0]
a * np.exp(-k*x[-1]) + 0.025 = y[-1]
```

Solving this gives:

```
a = (y[0]-0.025)/np.exp(-k*x[0])
e^(-k*(x[-1]-x[0])=(y[-1]-0.025)/(y[0]-0.025) # and then take logarithm

k = -np.log((y[-1]-0.025)/(y[0]-0.025))/(x[-1]-x[0])
a = (y[0]-0.025)/np.exp(-k*x[0])
```

gives `k=0.00026798747972760543` and `a=-0.80114087848462689`

This method can be used generaly, throw away as many points as necessarry to solve the equation exact and then use these values for starting optimal values

Comment: I think the data looks like a saturation function, which is exactly what the model describes when `a` is negative.  A linear model would not give a good fit.  (Of course it only has two parameters instead of three, so it's expected that the fit is worse, but the additional parameter reduces χ² enough to justify it.)

Comment: Solely relying on the first and last data point for the initial guesses is not the most robust approach, since they might be outliers.  It would be more useful to use linear regression in log space to determine the parameters.

Comment: I agree that taking the first and the last is not robust, but it doesn't really have to be, as curvefit will solve the problem.
In case curvefit doesn't find a solution with this guess you can still take other two samples or make more complex methods like taking all pairs of samples and take the average. But taking the first and the last (or basically any arbitrary two) will "most likely" help you find good initial guesses.